# Should there be race-specific tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I think I created the [Half-Orc] tag today when asking [Does the half orc's Savage Attack work when wild shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64100/23970) It made sense to me to tag it, as it's a feature unique to the Half Orc+Druid combination. *'If I'm going to tag it Druid, why wouldn't I tag it Half-Orc?'* I thought.

A few moments later I thought to tag [Does the half orc's Savage Attack work when wild shaped?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/64100/23970) with [Half-Orc]; that edit occasioned the following feedback: "...Tags should help to describe what the question is about, not just what it contains" and "I'm not sure we need a tag just for half-orcs...."

This all got me thinking and digging through the tags (5e core, just 'cause that was the only rulebook I had with me). We currently have questions tagged by race or class in the following numbers:

**Class:** Barbarian 45, Bard 49, Cleric 122, Druid 123, Fighter 70, Monk 136, Paladin 69, Ranger 68, Rogue 96, Sorcerer 80, Warlock 92, Wizard 123.

**Race:** Dwarf 6, Elf 11, Half-Elf 5, Halfling 10, Human 0, Gnome 0, Dragonborn 0 (though Draconic-bloodline 3), Half-Orc 1, Tiefling 3.

It sure doesn't seem like the racial tags are doing much lifting. Is there any need to re-evaluate the usefulness of the tags? Or whether *more* questions should be racially-tagged? Such as [I Roll To Seduce The Dragon! (or, Do doublings of proficiency bonus stack?)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67530/23970)

Comment: Previous discussion here: [Tag question - changeling tag](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/tag-question-changeling-tag)

Comment: Thanks, @SevenSidedDie. I searched around for "race" and "tag", but didn't come across this.

Comment: Another, slightly more recent previous discussion: [Add tag for Dwarf/Dwarves?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/3068/15469)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So, I don't know if we should have race-specific tags. But I *believe*, if we do have them, they should be for race-specific questions.

The questions you're asking about aren't really about half-orcs. They're about racial features which half-orcs happen to have. They would be exactly the same questions if elves, dwarves, or any other race had those features instead of half-orcs. The tag I'd suggest they probably need is [racial-traits](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/racial-traits).

As an example, this question - [How do I name a Half-Orc?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62577/15469) - **is**, fundamentally and specifically, about half-orcs. (It's not a particularly good question, admittedly, but that's besides the point here.) It had the [half-orc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-orc) tag until someone removed it. On that question, I think the [half-orc](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-orc) tag was completely appropriate.

For an example which is also a good question, this question - [Why are elves immune to a ghoul's paralyzing touch?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59528/why-are-elves-immune-to-a-ghouls-paralyzing-touch) - while not about half-orcs, is very much about elves, and has the [elf](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elf) tag to show that.

Comment: I think that's a good distinction--I've re-tagged my question with [racial-traits] rather than [half-orc]. Is there now anything that should be done to delete the [half-orc] tag, or will it just wither away with zero questions?

Comment: @nitsua60 It'll wither on its own.